# Why does this formula for $e$ work?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How would one prove that the following expression approaches $e$ when $n$ approaches infinity? $$(1+1/n)^n$$
edit: $e$ is the unique positive number a where the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x$

Comment: What do you mean by "work?" Are you asking why the limit exists in the first place? Otherwise, since you can show the limit exists, this is one possible definition of $e$.

Comment: As shown by the comment above, the question is not answerable unless you explain your definition of $e$ (in some curricula, $e$ is *defined* as the limit in your question, a choice which can be critiqued but...).

Comment: Your definition begs another question. How did you differentiate $a^x$? And probably another one: did you define (natural) logarithms beforehand?

Comment: If you have defined $a^{x}$ without using any fact about $e$ and $\log$ function and also established that $a^{x}$ is differentiable for all $x$ then your question makes sense. Assuming that you have covered the difficult part it is easy to show what you ask. Since $(e^{x})' = e^{x} > 0$ it follows there is an an inverse $\log$ function with $\log x = y$ if $e^{y} = x$ and it is differentiable with $(\log x)' = 1/x$ and therefore $(1/x)\log(1 + x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. To be continued...

Comment: Letting $x = 1/n$ we see that $n\log(1 + (1/n)) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence $\exp(n\log(1 + (1/n))) \to e$ i.e. $(1 + (1/n))^{n} \to e$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People first tried to calculate the derivative of exponential functions $f(x)=a^x$ by the definition of the derivative.

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}=a^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^{h}-1}{h}$$

Now you have the problem with the limit. Let's try to look for a special value of $a_0$ so that the limit is equal to 1.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a_0^{h}-1}{h}=1$$

For small $h$, we can rewrite

$$\frac{a_0^h-1}{h}\approx1$$

and solve for $a$

$$a_0\approx(1+h)^\frac{1}{h}$$

We can also substitute $n=1/h$ and let the limit go to $\infty$.

$$a_0=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$$

Today, we call this number $e$. Convergence can be proven by finding an upper and lower bound, and additionally proving that the series is monotonically increasing.

Comment: A slightly rigorous version would be use $(a_{0}^{h} - 1)/h = 1 + o(h)$ which translates to $a_{0} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (1/n) + o(1/n))^{n}$ and we still need to show that this is same as $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (1/n))^{n}$. This is not difficult but needs to be done.

Comment: You are totally right, but I gave up rigor for the sake of an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]=\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right]=$$

---

Apply l'Hôpital's rule:

---

$$\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right]=\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right]=\exp\left[\frac{1}{1+0}\right]=\exp[1]=e^1=e$$

Comment: But actually no one before $e$ discovering knows about this constant

Comment: L'Hospital's rule for this, you're kidding? It's a rate of variation.

Comment: @Bernard, it can work, but that is certainly dependent on how $e$ (and $\exp$, for that matter) was defined in the first place.

Comment: What are you definitions of $\exp$ and $\ln$?

Comment: @J.M. "It can work" as logical circles work, since this amounts to estimating the limit of $(f(\epsilon)-f(0))/\epsilon$ by computing $f'(0)$... (Note that the OP is repeatedly making this exact mistake and has been explained the problem. O well.)

Comment: @Did, you are right (as usual); I am merely saying that this could only be admissible assuming the starting points of $\log$, $\exp$, and $e$ were suitably defined, and is circular otherwise.

Comment: @J.M. Yes. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think of it $\dfrac{d a^x}{dx} = a^x *\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {a^h - 1}{h}$.  Let $p(a) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {a^h - 1}{h}$.

Given another base $b$ we have $\dfrac{d a^x}{dx} = \dfrac{d b^{x\log_b a}}{d x\log_b a}*\dfrac{d x\log_b a}{dx}=a^xp(b)\log_b a.$

So we have $p(a)= \log_b a*p(b)$.  So if we can find a number, $e$, where $p(e) = 1$ we'd have $\dfrac{de^x}{dx} = e^x$ and  $\dfrac{da^x}{dx} = a^x*\log_e a$.

So.. $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$ so

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{\frac 1n} - 1}{\frac 1n}= n(e^{1/n} -1) = 1$

Let $c_n = n(e^{1/n}-1)$ and $c_n \rightarrow 1$.  Then $e = (c_n/n+1)^n$.  So $e = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (c_n/n + 1)^n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1/n + 1)^n$

But this is a little backwards and not actually valid in that we are assuming an $e$ such that  $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$ exists in the first place.

More sensible would be to define $e = \lim (1 + 1/n)^n$ *first* and *then* show therefore $\dfrac {de^x}{dx} = e^x*\lim_{h\rightarrow 1}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} = e^x*\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n(e^{1/n} -1) = e^x*\lim n([(1 + 1/n)^n]^{1/n} - 1) = e^x * \lim n(1 + 1/n - 1) = e^x$.